# What is bootloader?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.4-kitkat, updates, rom-flashing

So I have Samsung Galaxy SII Plus(Gt-I9105P)
It has Stock android 4.1.2.(rooted).
I wanted to flash Cynogen Mode 11 M12
To do that, they say that i need to flash boot loader 4.2.2.

[link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s2-plus/orig-development/rom-cyanogenmod-11-t2800254)
What is it? I installed CWM when I rooted. Is that enough?
Should I install Android 4.2.2. before I install CM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you start your phone up you probably see a Samsung logo and an android logo... 
Basically, The system that opens this up is called the boot loader and you need to unlock it to gain root access... This allows you to edit system files.

See http://www.all-things-android.com/content/understanding-android-file-hierarchy

It will help you understand what exactly root is. CM needs to unlock your bootloader because it needs to  modify android files at the core of your phone.

Hope this helps,
Rahul

Comment: Thx @rahul. Got the general idea. So, should i install 4.2.2 before i install 4.4.4? Does boot loader comes with os(android)? Should i install the boot loader alone?

Comment: No bootloader and OS are completely different things and should have no problem in skipping any version if you want and your device support it

Comment: @freedom, so what should I do to update to KK?

Comment: Flash their bootloader if that's necessary then flash the 4.4 system image for your device that you should have...if you don't know how to flash then go to xda you'll probably use odin for that

Comment: @freedom,got it... So i need to flah the bootloader(only boot loader) and then 4.4 .. Thx

Comment: If it helps, the order how Android usually starts is that (1) the power goes on, (2) the bootloader software is started, which (3) loads the kernel and the ramdisk (a mini bundle of files), which in turn (4) loads the rest of Android.  If the bootloader is locked, you can't replace the kernel/ramdisk or android itself because a locked bootloader checks to see if the kernel has been modified from the manufacturer's kernel, and if so, the bootloader usually stops the boot.  Unlocking the bootloader gives you the freedom to load your own kernel and your own Android.